# Cross Domain policy allow Youtube

Tags: apache, security, centos, xss, content-security-policy

I ONLY want scripts from my site, youtube and addthis to be loaded, nothing else is allowed. This is my crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="my website url"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="www.youtube.com"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="ct1.addthis.com"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Can anybody tell me where I've gone wrong or how to verify that my site is using the crossdomain.xml file please?

Kind Regards,
Harry

edit:

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Content-Security-Policy: "allow 'self'; options inline-script; img-src 'self' data:" 

    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|crx|css|eot|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|m4a|m4v|manifest|mp4|oex|oga|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|safariextz|svgz?|ttf|vcf|webapp|webm|webp|woff|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset Content-Security-Policy
    </FilesMatch>
 </IfModule>
```

Where do I add `https://www.youtube.com` to this to allow my embedded videos to play? Here's the stack trace although I doubt it's very helpful.

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
Stack trace: Error: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at Error (native)
    at setupffoverrides (chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/onloadwff.js:151:86)
    at checkgenpwfillforms (chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/onloadwff.js:152:33)
    at receiveBG (chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/onloadwff.js:130:210)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at EventImpl.dispatchToListener (extensions::event_bindings:395:22)
    at Function.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
    at Event.publicClass.(anonymous function) [as dispatchToListener] (extensions::utils:65:26)
    at EventImpl.dispatch_ (extensions::event_bindings:378:35)
    at EventImpl.dispatch (extensions::event_bindings:401:17)
```

edit 2:

I've changed it to the following, but I'm still getting the same trace.

```
    Header set X-Content-Security-Policy: "allow 'self' https://www.youtube.com; options inline-script; img-src 'self' data:"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent scripts being loaded apart from those specified, you need a [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/), not a `crossdomain.xml` file.

A CSP can help prevent [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attacks because only authorised content is allowed to execute. So if a malicious user injects some script into the page, the script will not execute if `unsafe inline` is not specified by your policy.

### Update after edit

If you need YouTube to access your site cross-domain, then you need to implement [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/). This is essentially the output of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from your pages to allow other domains to bypass the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and access your content client side.

Comment: Hi, I didn't expect you to be replying so fast so I was half way through editing it!